# Typescript: generic function with variable arguments length

Tags: typescript, generics

I'm trying to convert this simple JavaScript function into Typescript:

```
function wrap(fn) {
  return function (...args) {
    return Promise.resolve(fn.apply(this, args));
  };
}
```

And this is what I have so far:

```
function wrapTs<TArgs extends any[], TReturn>(
  fn: (args: TArgs) => TReturn
): (args: TArgs) => Promise<TReturn> {
  return function inner(this: any, ...args: any[]): Promise<TReturn> {
    return Promise.resolve(fn.apply(this, args));
  };
}
```

But I'm getting error when trying to pass function arguments using `fn#apply`:

> Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type '[args: TArgs]'.

[Link to TS playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQDMCuA7AxggljDJAdzgEMoAVAZwB4KBBOAcyqUgTAwBNXSMBPANoBdADRIKAJTAI0cDAD4AFKCSoMALiRLSzKloZ6AlEgC8CidNnyjWnXoOMWJ80gAKcGAFtcVMHSs5RSQAb1U1JDgZINRMHHxCXAwMMDglBAALXy0%20fnEAOkLdFhyBEVt3Tx8-AOj5CzCQcIiIqOtCSu9fMHyoqhgAGwA3MCUUDHzyKAH%20dKyqcWKqIyNmpABfAG5QdaA)

What I'm missing here?

Thanks.

Comment: I think you are looking for https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=8&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/LAKApgHgDg9gTgFwAQDMCuA7AxggljDJAdzgEMoAVAZwB4KBBOAcyqUgTAwBNXSMBPANoBdADRIKAJTAI0cDAD4AFKCSoMALiRKAdHtLMqWhoYCUSALwKJ02fNNbd+w8cYtzVpAAU4MALa4VGB0tnKKSADeqmpIcDJhqJg4+IS4GBhgcEoIABaBWnz84no6BiyuZlo+-oHBUvHy1lEg0TExcXaE3r4BQTpxVDAANgBuYEooGKVQUEP82XlU4mVUpqatSAC+ANygm0A

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir thanks, this worked for me. If you interested please put your comment as answer, I'll accept it